# Postgres 14 tds_fdw for SQL Server requires setting ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNING

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, freetds, tds-fdw

I am looking into establishing foreign data wrapper between PostgreSQL 14 and remote SQL Server 2014. I do not have administrative-level access to the remote SQL Server, thus need to make changes only at Postgres.

The error I currently encounter is below.

> DB-Library notice: Msg #: 7405, Msg state: 1,
> Msg: Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.

Where do I set `ANSI_NULLS` and `ANSI_WARNINGS`? I don't mind going lower level at `freetds` or `libdb` level if necessary. The option to do this does not seem to be available from within `tds_fdw`. From this issue, https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw/issues/186 it does not seem that this feature will be available.

My environment is RockyLinux 8.5, PostgreSQL 14.

Comment: You should issue `set ansi_nulls, ansi_warnings on;` immediately before the remote query.

Comment: where do i do that? i'm not using interactive sql server client. i'm using foreign data wrapper within postgres.

Comment: Does this error occur on connection or on query? If on query, you should be able to `SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_WARNINGS ON; SELECT * FROM my_table;`

Comment: error on connection. i tried within query but doesn't work. Same error came out. -> Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection